# Center row of buttons in html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center a row of buttons in an html div.

```
<div id="menuBarLine" style="position:relative; float:left; width:24%; background-color: black">
        <div id="toggleFullscreen" style="color:red; visibility:visible; position:relative; float:right" ;>
            <button title="Fullscreen" onClick="fullscreen();">Fullscreen</button>
        </div>
        <div id="toggleMap" style="display:none; position:relative; float:right" ;>
            <button title="Show/Hide Map" onClick="toggleMap();">Image Map</button>
        </div>
        <div id="toggleCarousel" style="color:red; visibility:visible; position:relative; float:right" ;>
            <button title="Show/Hide Thumbnails" onClick="toggle_carousel();">Thumbnails</button>
        </div>
<div id="toggleBib" style="color:red; visibility:visible; position:relative; float:right" ;>
            <button title="Show/Hide Bibliography" onClick="toggleBib();">Bibliography</button>
        </div>
        <div id="showGalleryMenuButton" style="display: block; position:relative; float:right" ;>
            <button id="showGalleryMenuButtonButton" title="Show/Hide Gallery Menu" onClick="toggle_visibility('menu');">Galleries</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

So I want to center all those buttons in the menuBarLine div. See the site I'm working on for a visual: http://www.blakearchive.org/blake/public/exhibits/canterbury.html

I want to center the buttons across the top of the right column. I tried margin:0 auto in the div, but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using center tags. <center>my button</center>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Set `text-align:center` to menuBarLine.

2- Remove this attributes from all buttons

```
display:none; position:relative; float:right
```

3- and add `display:inline-block` for each button.

Comment: **display: inline-block; (missing an "s" on number 3).